# What does the phrase 'across the head' mean?

Tags: word-usage

In the following sentence, I don't understand the phrase 'across the head'. Please explain it to me.

> The man hit the woman twice across the head.

Answer (score 0):

And don't forget "upside the head". But we won't go there.

This is an example of very localized dialects. Imagine a man and a woman standing face to face within arms' reach of each other. The man raises his arm up and slightly away from his body. When his hand is at head height, he swings his arm in front of himself, hitting the woman on the side of her head with his hand, flat not fisted. The second time might be with the same hand on the same side of the woman's head or with the other hand on the other side of her head.

You won't hear many people speak this way. And you shouldn't speak this way.